# Image Captioning problem where we expect a specifc type of answer depending on the objects in the image

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, image-classification, computer-vision

I'm working on an ML problem where I'm trying to generate captions for the images, but depending on the category of the image, the caption should contain specific information. For example, if the image is a scene from category A, we expect the caption to look for X and Y in the image, and talk about them. if the image is a scene from the B category or a specific B object is detected in it, I want the model to look for X2, Y2, and Z2 in the image and describe them. Which types of papers or keywords can I look into for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Assuming that the category is known, it can be done simply by training different models, each specific to to a category.